# How to prevent Lambda LINQ expression from adding a null value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm using a LINQ expression that iterates over a list execute the query as follows:

```
feedVideos.Add(vid.Where(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName).FirstOrDefault());
```

This expression adds a null to the list if there aren't any object present. I don't know if it's a normal behavior but how do I make it so it doesn't add anything when there isn't any object present in the list?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns null if a match is not found

Answer (score 9):

Rather than using `FirstOrDefault` to get a possibly null value, simply use `Take` to limit the sequence to one item, leaving you with a sequence of size zero or one, that you can add to the list:

```
feedVideos.AddRange(vid.Where(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName).Take(1));
```

Comment: This is very clean. I like it!

Answer (score 7):

Use a simple `if`:

```
var result=vid.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName);
if(result!=null)
{
 feedVideos.Add(result);
}
```

If your list doesn't have values, then `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`, so, yes, that is the normal behavior.

Comment: the default part of the FirstOrDefault is defined as default value of the type - which is indeed null - and gets return as you said when no items are passing the filter.

Answer (score 4):

`FirstOrDefault` yields a null value if the condition cannot be met. You will have to add the conditional check outside the call to `Add`.

Also, you can simplify the Where and FirstOrDefault.

```
var v = vid.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName);
if (v != null)
{
    feedVideos.Add(v);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly adding an element, and using the FirstOrDefault function which will return null for class types if the query doesn't materialize any result.

If you want to avoid these nulls you must split the query and the addition:

```
var item = vid.Where(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName).FirstOrDefault();

if(item != null)
    feedVideos.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use this a lot, it is better to create an **Extension Method**:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool AddIfNotNull<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        bool added = false;

        if(item != null)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            added = true;
        }

        return added;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
feedVideos.AddIfNotNull(vid.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UserName == friend.Friend_UserName));
```